# Cannot register logging in dotnet core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, .net-core

I created a new dotnet core project issuing:

```
dotnet new mvc -au none -o aspnet_app
```

And then followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to add logging to the app

So I added COnfigureLogging to Program.BuildWebHost

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) => 
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

And also modified Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

But when in my HomeController I try to use it:

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger) {
    _logger = logger;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Index action!");
    return View();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
  An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'aspnet_app.Controllers.HomeController'.
```

--

using dotnet core 2.1.105

Comment: According to the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973991/cannot-register-logging-in-dotnet-core-2-1) `CreateDefaultBulder` already enables logging. Maybe you're having a collision there. Either way - there you have a working example. Compare to it and see what you're doing differently.

Comment: I tried commenting out all the configuration code but I still get the same error

Comment: Are you sure you use `ILogger<HomeController>` and not just `ILogger`? Because this error usually indicates that you are trying to resolve `ILogger`.

Comment: You are right @Evk, somehow my code got mixed up, I also had loglevel warning in appsettings.config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are over coding it.  [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/0b5cb8a8b8370a74b6ccbdb9f790e939be788dd3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L150) builds the logger automatically getting
 [hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/0b5cb8a8b8370a74b6ccbdb9f790e939be788dd3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L183)  you dont actually need to add antying to program.cs or your startup.

Just edit the basic project and add this and it will work.

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Index action!");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You are right, the problem is I was using `ILogger` instead of `ILogger<HomeController>` and the loglevel was set to warning

Comment: BTW I love that you gave the dotnet command made it a lot easier for me to test this and get it working.   I will remember to do that in the future.